# Gain of Non-Inverting Amplifier Does Not vary with Resistor Values

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, potentiometer, gain, non-inverting

I am trying to build a non-inverting amplifier using a LM7171 op amp, and I am implementing it with potentiometers as Rf and R2 so that I can smoothly control the gain of the amplifier (and easily check if its working correctly). I am applying +/- 15 V to the op amp. When I adjust the potentiometer's resistance the gain does not change as expected, or noticeably at all. Setup is shown below with traces when the resistances are Rf=Ri=540 Ohm and Rf=1.8 kOhm, Ri=540 Ohm, and as can be seen the gain/amplitude is the same for the different resistances used. The yellow output on the oscilloscope is the output of the amplifier, and the green is directly from a t-connector to the function generator's output.

I have used two different op amps and got the same behavior, so it is not broken, and all connections seem good. I measure the values of the potentiometer so am confident they are as described. Any ideas what might cause this? Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

100 kHz sinusoids. 
[image]

[image]

Setup as voltage follower

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You also have a large phase shift. Something odd going on. You have no DC path on the non-inverting input. That's going to cause the input capacitor to charge up or down until it hits one of the supply rails.

Comment: The LM7171 has a very, very fast slew rate and 200 MHz at unity gain. I think your output is showing a gain of about 1.5 in the setup. This looks more to me about the breadboard's pF, which is getting well into the 1k zone with that frequency. Use dead-bug construction and see what happens.

Comment: Jonk, when you say pF does that stand for parasitic feedback or are you simply referring to the capacitance (i.e. picoFarads)? You're saying that with such a high capacitance from the breadboard it gives a higher equivalent impedance in place of the pots' values changing the gain from what would be expected?

Comment: @wondersm I mean the fact that there is about 5 pF between adjacent rows on those boards!! Those breadboards aren't mean to be used with those frequencies. (Well, I don't think so.)

Answer (score 5):

The phase shift is the give-away. You are bandwidth limited. You need a faster op-amp, or a lower frequency.

Comment: Yup, 18.88 MHz. I hadn't spotted that.

Comment: The op-amp has a 200 MHz unity-gain bandwidth so I was thinking it should be fine with only a gain of 2-3x around 20 MHz. I tested again at 100 kHz and the same behavior happens as well. I added two pictures to the original post to show this, and they are for the same resistance values as at 19 MHz; the waveform with the more pronounced artifacts has the higher Rf value, which actually yields a lower amplitude. I also added a DC path to ground as Transistor suggested, though that doesn't seem to make a difference. Does this suggest anything else?

Comment: OK, based on your 100kHz test you probably aren't bandwidth limited. I don't see any decoupling caps. Put a small ceramic as close as you can to the op-amp. If that doesn't work, keep simplifying until it works as expected. Remove the pots and connect the output to the minus input for a gain of 1. Remove the input cap. Lower the frequency even more.

Comment: Mattman, I used bypass capacitors earlier but removed them as they seemed to have no impact. I've reimplemented them and converted it to a voltage follower as you suggested, picture above. Note I need the input capacitor, otherwise huge and strange oscillations are induced. In this configuration low frequencies are passed normally, but higher ones are not (pictures above), even though 1 MHz should be well within the bandwidth of the opamp. Would this imply that the problem lies with the frequency response of the breadboard itself?

Comment: OK, I found another clue. "The LM7171 is stable for gains as low as +2 or −1". Most op-amps are stable at unity gain, but some high performance ones are not. Sorry, I lead you astray on that one. Try this test: Use 100kHz. Set your gain to 3 with fixed resistors. A resistor from the + terminal to ground as Transistor suggested is very important, try 100k. Always use decoupling caps, issues caused by the lack of them will get you when you least expect it.

Comment: Ah, I should have caught that too. I made the DC path to ground from the input 120k and used Rf=1.48 kOhm, R2 = 798 Ohm for a gain of around 3. When I apply voltage to the op amp and produce the sinusoid, it passes the sinusoid at 100 kHz and up to MHz, although it still has a phase shift of apparently 180 degrees. When I replace Rf with a potentiometer of the same value the performance remains, but when I increase the value of Rf the sinusoid does not increase in amplitude, and at high frequencies (~5 MHz) actually decreases in amplitude. I am applying +/- 15 V and using an input of 800 mV.

Comment: The amplitude of the signals being passed should be plenty far away from the rails. With a gain*bandwidth of 200 MHz and such a high slew rate, I wouldn't expect to have issues with this. Even at 1 kHz the gain is not affected by changing the pots value. I am at a loss... The only thing I can think of is I am using a .01 and .1 uF bypass capacitor on each power supply instead of the .01 and 2 uF specified by the data sheet.

Comment: Turning off the power supplied to V- barely changes the passed sinusoid at all, while turning off the power supplied to V+ while keeping V- on results in a huge, seemingly positive clipped pulse, with the same phase as the input. Perhaps I am not supplying voltage to the negative rail correctly? If you have two separate power supplies and want to use them to supply +/- V with the ground in between how would you properly implement that on a breadboard?

Answer (score 4):

You need to connect a high-value resistor between the op amp’s  + terminal and ground. All op amps have small dc currents that flow in or out of their input terminals, and they need a dc path for these currents. 
If you measure the dc level at the output of the op amp, you will see that the output is not at the ground, even when there is no input. 
So, the op-amp “bias point” is incorrect. Try 100k or so.